# How to Refresh/Reload Image inside JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, background-image, repaint

I need to reload the JPanel's background image, when data submitted to Database.
I create JPanel that populate image from Database. And when i updated the image, and submit it, the background automatically change.
I also try to use repaint() and revalidate() but it wont work. 
It must to restart application and run again, it works.

This is my code to display background in JPanel.

```
public void getLogo(Company company, PanelCompany view) {
        JPanel panel = new BackgroundImage(company.getLogoBlob());
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.setVisible(true);
        panel.setBounds(10, 10, 120, 120);
        view.getPanelPhoto().add(panel);
}
```

This my helper class :

```
public class BackgroundImage extends JPanel{
    private Image image;

    public BackgroundImage (InputStream input) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
        super.paintComponent(grphcs);
        Graphics2D gd = (Graphics2D) grphcs.create();
        gd.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        gd.dispose();
    }
}
```

Any solutions? Thanks for your attention before :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your helper class should set it's own size.

Second, you should just use the `Graphics` instance of the `JPanel`.

```
public class BackgroundImage extends JPanel{
    private Image image;

    public BackgroundImage (InputStream input) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(input);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
        super.paintComponent(grphcs);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grphcs;
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
}
```

Now your call would look like this.

```
public void getLogo(Company company, PanelCompany view) {
        JPanel panel = new BackgroundImage(company.getLogoBlob());
        view.getPanelPhoto().add(panel);
}
```

Your `PanelCompany` class **must** use a layout manager.  Here's [Oracle's Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Pick one.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: Consider overriding `getPreferredSize`, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513)